# When using bootstrap-multiselect and 'Select All' is selected, it is not triggering the AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have two dropdown lists which one of them is dependent on the other. Let's call is multiselect 1 and multiselect 2. Based on the value selected in multiselect1, multiselect 2's dropdown list changes via ajax call.

I am triggering my ajax call based on 'onChange'.
However, when user opens the page and as default all values will be selected in multiselect 1 but as my current set-up is only for onchange, how to trigger my ajax call based on all selected as default? 
On change AJAX Call which perfectly works except when all selected --->

```
 $('#market-select').multiselect(

                {

                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
                filterBehavior: 'value',
                enableFiltering: true,
                buttonWidth: '270px',
                onChange: function (option, checked) {
                    var markets = $('#market-select option:selected');
                    var selected = [];
                    var json = "'" + JSON.stringify(selected) + "'";
                    $(markets).each(function (index, markets) {
                        selected.push($(this).val())
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: _config.GetCampaignsByMarket,
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            marketValue: selected
                        }),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function (data) {
                           var items = ''; //the original example which makes constant call to dom when the other one makes call only twice
                            $('.select-ajax').empty();
                         $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                 $('.select-ajax').append('<option selected value="' + val.CampaignInitiative + '">' + val.CampaignInitiative + '</option>');
                            items += "<option value='" + val.CampaignInitiative + "'>" + val.CampaignInitiative + "</option>";

                           });






                             $('.select-ajax').multiselect('rebuild');



                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                        }
                    });



                }


            });
```

Attemt to initialize ajax call on initialization which clearly does not work. I am going crazy at this point.

```
 $("#market-select").multiselect('selectAll', false);
            $("#market-select").multiselect('updateButtonText');

            var allMarkets = $('#market-select:selected').map(function (a, item) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: _config.GetCampaignsByMarket,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        marketValue: allMarkets
                    }),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = ''; //the original example which makes constant call to dom when the other one makes call only twice
                        $('.select-ajax').empty();
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                            $('.select-ajax').append('<option selected value="' + val.CampaignInitiative + '">' + val.CampaignInitiative + '</option>');
                            items += "<option value='" + val.CampaignInitiative + "'>" + val.CampaignInitiative + "</option>";

                        });
                        //var options = data.map(function (o) {
                        //    return '<option selected value="' + o.CampaignInitiative + '">' + o.CampaignInitiative + '</option>'; // faster as it only accesses the DOM twice, compared to the original's 2+N array items.'
                        //}).join('');






                        $('.select-ajax').multiselect('rebuild');



                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onSelectAll) bootstrap-multiselect has onSelectAll configuration. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: so now it works by adding configurations selectAll, deselectAll. However, when try to initialize with allSelected, it is still not triggering ajax call but only if I click it. Any insights?